# Run As Administrator Shortcut Without Password Prompt

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac

I have installed a program on Windows 7 that needs Admin rights to run properly. When running on Windows XP; I used the `runas` command with the `savecred` switch to create a shortcut that opened the application and run as Administrator without prompting for a password.

I have tried the most options found on the internet with the properties dialogue of the shortcut and messed around with the Scheduled Tasks option, but to no avail.I am running Windows 7 Home Premium, 32-bit.

I have programs installed on my computer that have a Administrator Icon Overlay and seam to run as Admin without prompting for credentials. How can I achieve the same manually?

Comment: Could you list the application(s) which behave this way?

Answer (score 4):

I believe Task Scheduler should do it.

"How to Create a Elevated Program Shortcut without a UAC Prompt"

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html

Other possibilities:

"How to Run a Program as an Administrator in Windows 7"

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11841-run-administrator.html

Comment: There's also http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/193743-elevated-program-shortcut-create-standard-user.html

Comment: The idea is clever: creating a task with stored admin password, then running the task via a shortcut. But for GUI applications, it only works if you're already logged in as the user the task is created for. Otherwise the GUI never shows up.

Comment: Link-only answers are not good answers.

Answer (score 3):

Try messing around with "cacls" and "icacls" in cmd.

1.) Command + R

2.) icacls /?

3.) cacls /?

This allows you to elevate the permissions of a certain file/directory. I use the command, "icacls  :(F,MA,GA,GE,X,AS)

Comment: This would be a great answer if you provided a powershell snippet to demonstrate.

Answer (score -5):

To configure an application to always run elevated

1. Right-click an application that is not likely to have been assigned an administrative token, such as a word processing application.
2. Click Properties, and then select the Compatibility tab.
3. Under Privilege Level, select Run this program as an administrator, and then click OK.

[Found here on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: It will still give you the UAC prompt and prompt you for the administrator password, so, no.