# Run As Administrator Shortcut Without Password Prompt for an appilication

Tags: windows-7, administrator, windows-domain

We are on a domain here and an application will only run either if you are on the local administrator account or you have full admin rights to the machine.

So what I need to do is a way to run the application with the full same permissions as for the local administrator account and without having to enter a password.

I am not talking about when you can right click and hit compatibility run as administrator etc.

Comment: This seems like what you want to do. http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/

Answer (score -2):

Turn off uac for the computer. The reason you are seeing the prompt is because you are running it as an administrator. Either crate a scheduled task to run elevated or turn off UAC. No way around it that I know of. Maybe someone else more knowledgeable may know.

Comment: Turning off UAC won't change the fact the program will require an administrator privilage to work.  Also the obvious reason this is a stupid thing to do, it makes your computer, less secure.

Comment: No it doesn't but it won't annoy you with the popup anymore. I never claimed it was secure. What do you suggest @Ramhound?

This is a duplicate question anyway. http://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt

Comment: Discover what privilage is required by the program, and depending on what privilage it is exactly, elevate the user group's privilage to include it.