# How to let standard user run an application that asks for administrator previleges

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, administrator, uac

I have an application that asks for adminin previleges to run on a user account with standard previleges on a Windows 7 OS. Assuming that there is no way of him knowing the Admin password what would be the best solution to bypass this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grant admin rights on an application](http://superuser.com/questions/512921/grant-admin-rights-on-an-application), [Run As Administrator Shortcut Without Password Prompt](http://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt)

Comment: Provide the user the required permissions to run it without administrator permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you need to add admin previleges to the program needed to that user.
[This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/) explains in details how to bypass this problem.

Comment: Doing what you describe still requires the user providing the require administrator authentication in order to do the intial permission escalation on the process

Comment: You just have to do it once, next time it won't ask again

Answer (score 1):

My kids record in-game video for some of their games using Bandicam, which requires admin permissions to run. I use [RunasSpc](http://robotronic.de/runasspcEn.html) to launch the program as administrator.

I configured a RunasSpc instance specifically for Bandicam, and gave the kids a desktop shortcut that kicks off the RunasSpc process and initiates Bandicam startup.

Once an admin sets up RunasSpc, using it is literally so simple that a 6-year-old can do it.